# Is there any text editor online capable of recording macros?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-editor

I am a looking for a good text editor with a simple and powerful macro-recording functionality that should be open souce and Javascript/jQuery based.

Comment: Try asking this here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok, didn't know about that.

Here's the new question in case someone drops around:
http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2583/is-there-any-text-editor-online-capable-of-recording-macros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, best web editor is Ace, I don't know if you can record macros from UI, but It has an API, so you can add your custom commands:

http://ace.c9.io/#nav=howto

It's used by [Cloud9](https://c9.io/) IDE